# Modal position error

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm a beginner in CSS. I'm editing a modal window but I'm having problem with placement. This modal window, whenever I change the resolution of the browser it has a positioning problem that is shown in the screenshot. I need the width and height sizes to be expressed in %.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Gpyh.png)

Modal HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="erroAdocaoAindaNaoConcluida" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="erroAdocaoAindaNaoConcluidaLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" align="center">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>

                <span class="titulo_modal" id="erroAdocaoAindaNaoConcluidaLabel">Detectamos um erro</span>

            </div>

            <div class="modal-body" align="center">
                <p class="titulo_form"> Você só pode adotar um animal por vez.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">

                <button type="button" class="tamanho_btn_adotar btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

modal-content CSS:

```
.modal-content{
   position:relative;width:45%; 
   background-color:#fff;
   -webkit-background-clip:padding-box;
   background-clip:padding-box;
   border:1px solid #999;
   border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
   border-radius:6px;
   outline:0;
   -webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 9px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
   box-shadow:0 3px 9px rgba(0,0,0,.5)
}

.modal-content{
   -webkit-box-shadow:0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
   box-shadow:0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.5)
}
```

modal-body CSS:

```
.modal-body{position:relative;padding:15px}
```

modal-dialog CSS:

```
.modal-dialog{width:600px;margin:30px auto}
.modal-dialog{
   -webkit-transform:translate(0,0);
   -ms-transform:translate(0,0);
   -o-transform:translate(0,0);
   transform:translate(0,0)
 }

.modal-dialog{
   position:relative;
   width:auto; 
   top:20px; 
   left:8%;
   margin:10px
}
```

Comment: can u send url of your bug page, so that i will try it with firebug

Comment: You want modal window to be centered both horizontally and vertically relatively to screen, yes?

Comment: The page is https://segundo-ong.firebaseapp.com/painel.html @GaneshPutta

Comment: Yes, @VadimOvchinnikov

Comment: remove `left: 8%;` from `.modal-dialog`, remove `position: relative;` from `.modal-content`, add `margin: auto;` to `.modal-content`. also you can add `min-width: 200px` to `.modal-content`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed something in your css and add extra elements, just try the below snippet

```css
.modal-content {
 position: relative;
 width: 45%;
 background-color: #fff;
 -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
 background-clip: padding-box;
 border: 1px solid #999;
 border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
 border-radius: 6px;
 outline: 0;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
 box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.modal-content {
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
 box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.5)
}
.modal-dialog {
 width: 600px;
 margin: 30px auto
}
.modal-dialog {
 -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
 -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
 -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
 transform: translate(0, 0)
}
.modal-dialog {
 position: relative;
 width: auto;
 top: 20px;
 margin: 10px
}
.modal-body {
 position: relative;
 padding: 15px
}
@media (max-width:480px) {
.modal-content {
 width: 100%;
}
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> Launch demo modal </button>
<!--<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">-->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="erroAdocaoAindaNaoConcluidaLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header" align="center">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <span class="titulo_modal" id="erroAdocaoAindaNaoConcluidaLabel">Detectamos um erro</span> </div>
      <div class="modal-body" align="center">
        <p class="titulo_form"> Você só pode adotar um animal por vez.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="tamanho_btn_adotar btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your Parent Div to position absolute.

Answer (score 0):

@Isaac Meneses Please replace following css properties in your code.

```css
.modal-dialog {
    position: relative;
    margin: 30px auto;
    width: 40%;
}

.modal-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    border-radius: 6px;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexible implementation. Will work even in case when `width` and `height` are set to `auto`.

```css
.modal {
  /* Just styles for demonstation */
  /* setting width and height is optional */
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
</div>
```